# Sublime Text: change selected text with some format

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

**What I'm trying to do:**

Format selected text, with the use of a custom shortcut.

**An example:**

Select `Home` + some shortcut --> `{% trans "Home" %}`

**Where I'm stuck:**

I had searched around, but i didn't find a solution.
It seems can be resolvable in a programmatic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is exactly what packags like [WrapIt](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/WrapIt) or  [CodeWrapper](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CodeWrapper) have been designed for.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what exactly you're trying to do, [this walkthrough](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html) is supposed to aid people to create custom shortcuts that can be used for text manipulation.